# SQL Server: How do I use EXECUTE sp_executesql inside a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL server 2014.

I'm trying to create a dynamic WHERE clause, by executing a varchar(max) as code inside the WHERE clause.

Why isn't it working?

```
 SET @tiendas='(ID_CO=20 OR ID_CO=22 OR ID_CO=23 OR ID_CO=27 OR ID_CO=35 OR ID_CO=39 OR ID_CO=45 OR ID_CO=48 OR ID_CO=55 OR ID_CO=58)';

    SELECT
        FECHA_DCTO,
        ID_CO,
        DETALLE_DOC,
        NOM_CLI_CONTADO,
        (SUM(TOT_VENTA)) AS ventaTotal
    FROM 
        db.dbo.myTable
    WHERE
        (EXECUTE sp_executesql @tiendas) 
        AND ID_CO > 1
    GROUP BY  
        DETALLE_DOC, ID_CO, FECHA_DCTO, NOM_CLI_CONTADO
```

**EDIT**

Why isn't it still not working?
I get these errors (translating, my SQLSMS is in spanish): 
- Líne 4 You must declare table variable "@tablaFacturas". 
- Líne 13 You must declare the scalar variable "@desde".

```
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@desde char(8) = null, 
@hasta char(8) = null,
@minimo int = null,
@ciudad int = null

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @tiendas varchar(max);

DECLARE @tablaFacturas TABLE
(
    fecha char(8), 
    CO char(8),
    consecutivo varchar(max),
    nombreCliente varchar(max),
    ventaTotal int
);

SET @tiendas='(ID_CO=20 OR ID_CO=22 OR ID_CO=23 OR ID_CO=27 OR ID_CO=35 OR ID_CO=39 OR ID_CO=45 OR ID_CO=48 OR ID_CO=55 OR ID_CO=58)';

DECLARE @dynamicCode nvarchar(max)=
N' INSERT INTO
    @tablaFacturas
SELECT
    FECHA_DCTO,
    ID_CO,
    DETALLE_DOC,
    NOM_CLI_CONTADO,
    (SUM(TOT_VENTA)) AS ventaTotal
FROM 
    moda.dbo.CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS
WHERE'
    + @tiendas +
    N' AND FECHA_DCTO >= @desde
    AND FECHA_DCTO <= @hasta
    AND ventaTotal >= @minimo
GROUP BY  
    DETALLE_DOC, ID_CO, FECHA_DCTO, NOM_CLI_CONTADO';

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] @dynamicCode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass EXECUTE where you want, first you need to build query.

```
SET @tiendas = '(ID_CO=20 OR ID_CO=22 OR ID_CO=23 OR ID_CO=27 OR ID_CO=35 OR ID_CO=39 OR ID_CO=45 OR ID_CO=48 OR ID_CO=55 OR ID_CO=58)';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
  N'SELECT
    FECHA_DCTO,
    ID_CO,
    DETALLE_DOC,
    NOM_CLI_CONTADO,
    (SUM(TOT_VENTA)) AS ventaTotal
  FROM db.dbo.myTable
  WHERE ' + @tiendas +        
  N' AND ID_CO > 1
  GROUP BY  DETALLE_DOC, ID_CO, FECHA_DCTO, NOM_CLI_CONTADO';

-- debug
SELECT @sql;

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
   @sql;
```

You ought to read also **[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)**

**EDIT:**

You try to `INSERT INTO` table variable which is in another scope.
When you use Dynamic-SQL it is executed with new scope. Use:

```
DECLARE @dynamicCode nvarchar(max)=
N' 
SELECT
    FECHA_DCTO,
    ID_CO,
    DETALLE_DOC,
    NOM_CLI_CONTADO,
    (SUM(TOT_VENTA)) AS ventaTotal
FROM 
    moda.dbo.CMMOVIMIENTO_VENTAS
WHERE'
    + @tiendas +
    N' AND FECHA_DCTO >= @desde
    AND FECHA_DCTO <= @hasta
    AND ventaTotal >= @minimo
GROUP BY  
    DETALLE_DOC, ID_CO, FECHA_DCTO, NOM_CLI_CONTADO';


INSERT INTO @tablaFacturas
EXEC(@dynamicCode);
```

Comment: thanks so much, great help, much closer to success!
my code was a bit more complicated, still not working, can you let me know if I'm missing anything else? I've just edited the code.

Comment: @quelquecosa Please don't write it is not working. Specify what error you get.

Comment: @quelquecosa Also don't edit your post like you did, because you invalidated my answer. You should write EDIT: and below paste new code

Comment: So sorry. This is the error I get (translating, my SQLSMS is in spanish):
Líne 4
You must declare table variable "@tablaFacturas".
Líne 13
You must declare the scalar variable "@desde".

Comment: They ARE declared though, that's why I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: I would like to pass table variable, do you know how? I will read that document you suggested, thanks.

Comment: @quelquecosa Don't pass anything, use INSERT INTO EXEC

Comment: I tried, but I don't think I am putting it in the right place. Could you please paste all the code from my EDIT with the INSERT INTO EXEC??

Comment: Ok great, that got rid of the "Líne 4 You must declare table variable '@tablaFacturas'." This one is still coming up, however: Líne 13 You must declare the scalar variable "@desde"

Comment: @quelquecosa Sorry I am done, this is 3rd question. I answered for your first two. Accept it or not. If you need futher help ask new question but don't edit this one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create the entire query in varchar(max):

```
SET @tiendas='(ID_CO=20 OR ID_CO=22 OR ID_CO=23 OR ID_CO=27 OR ID_CO=35 OR ID_CO=39 OR ID_CO=45 OR ID_CO=48 OR ID_CO=55 OR ID_CO=58)';

SET @Query = '
SELECT
        FECHA_DCTO,
        ID_CO,
        DETALLE_DOC,
        NOM_CLI_CONTADO,
        (SUM(TOT_VENTA)) AS ventaTotal
    FROM 
        db.dbo.myTable
    WHERE ' + @tiendas + ' AND ID_CO > 1
    GROUP BY  
        DETALLE_DOC, ID_CO, FECHA_DCTO, NOM_CLI_CONTADO';

EXEC (@Query)
```